# Adding paramater to large SQL Statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a large and somewhat complex SQL script that I'm using in .Net as below..

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.IO;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\myscript.sql");
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of the SQL script I have an ID value that needs to be a parameter that I pass in from my code, How can I do this? If I use a SQLCommand I could see the script becoming quite complex. Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a stored procedure?

Comment: You can have a place holder in the 'C:\\myscript.sql' file it self something like #ID# and after reading into 'script' variable  .. use string.replace with #ID# to the value you want.  i,e like script = script.Replace("#ID#",1); then use that. In this approach myscript.sql will not be used as is for running query but should solve your issue while running from the code. If this helps please let me know i will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify params in file by their index ({0} input to String.Format) and use string.format to provide actual value in code.

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\myscript.sql");
        string fileContent = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        //fileContent = "Select * from ABC where COL1 = '{0}'";
        string Col1Value = "Col1Values";
        string fileString = String.Format(fileContent,Col1Value);
```